# Find Port number

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have IP address of a specific device which opens TCP listener. (But in documentation I can not find default port number.)

---

Is there any way to find which port number does the device open for connection ?

> System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient client = new
>   System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient(); client.Connect(ipAddress, port);

Comment: Please share information about the device and/or software.

Answer (score 2):

In a word, no.

Unless it is using a [known protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers) it could be anything between 1024 and 65535. There is no "default" unless it's officially been given a designation by the IANA.

Comment: Think your answer will help as I just find that it use  RSIB or VXI-11 protocols.

Answer (score 2):

Use a port scanner like https://www.heise.de/download/product/portscan-70308 to scan for open ports.

Comment: ... and which one is _the_ port that needs to be used? :P

Comment: I clicked approve on the edit by @codelab. However, it seems that the edit is a spam and should be rejected.

Comment: @bahrep It is not spam, it is an example. Change it if you have a better one.

Comment: Yes it is a sample!!